# Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/J:/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas_1.2.1.v201302050732.jar!/dtdsAndSchemas/javaee_6.xsd)

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler

I am using eclipse Kepler I imported some java projects into workspace, and all `web.xml` files are showing error like this

> Referenced file contains errors
>   (jar:file:/J:/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas_1.2.1.v201302050732.jar!   /dtdsAndSchemas/javaee_6.xsd)
>   **My web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0"
metadata-complete="true">
```

is it the problem with jar file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete this:     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      from the 3rd line.